# Python odbc; how to find all tables in an odbc

Tags: python, odbc

Is there any way to get a list of all tables available through an odbc connection.

I have to fetch data from tables that are generated along the way, and therefore I don't know the names in advance.

Comment: query [ODBC Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how is that applied in python odbc?

Comment: Which [Python ODBC library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC) are you using?

Comment: ODBC (and not pyODBC)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

(the ODBC driver was not specifie at time of this answer)

From [PyODBC documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Features#Miscellaneous_ODBC_Functions):

> Most of the ODBC catalog functions are available as methods on Cursor objects. The results are presented as SELECT results in rows that are fetched normally. The [Cursor](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) page documents these, but it may be helpful to refer to [Microsoft's ODBC documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

```
cnxn   = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
for row in cursor.tables():
    print row.table_name
```

---

*EDIT: as OP specified using "Anaconda ODBC":*

As far as I know, there is no direct access to those data from PyWin32-odbc (as I think this is what Anacondas uses). Depending your underlying DB they might be a "system table" that you might query. Something like `sys.objects` or `dbo.sysobjects` or `information_schema.tables` or ... (RDBMS vendors are very creative in that area).

Please see the doc of the underlying RDBMS for more info. Or (as of myself, I would strongly push toward that), file a request to install a more versatile ODBC driver...

Comment: Thx. Though, I am using the standard anaconda package, and I can only use odbc and not pyodbc (and I can't just install packages due to security) - the cursor in odbc does not have tables() attribute. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @user2866103 Edited for PyWin32-odbc

Comment: This is the best answer after hours of searching SO!