# Retrieve list of tables from Microsoft Access database (mdb) using JaDeBeAPI and UCanAccess from python

Tags: python, ms-access, ucanaccess, jaydebeapi

I'm trying to retrieve a list of tables from an MS Access mdb database file from Python using JayDeBeApi combined with UCanAccess. Querying the database works fine, though I cannot find out how top list all tables. I've been googling and trying for days now, but was not able to find a solution.

Anyone can help?

Thanks, best,
Max

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python odbc; how to find all tables in an odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522873/python-odbc-how-to-find-all-tables-in-an-odbc)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created the connection using Import pyodbc: run this

```
for i in cursor.tables(tableType='Table'):
    print(i.table_name)
```

That should give you a list of all the tables in the MS access Db